# rails generate set default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding, locate

I need to set the default locale to spanish on my application.

These are the lines of my file application.rb:

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
    Rails.application.config.i18n.default_locale = :es

  end
```

But, when I generate the scaffold the inflection is wrong. It´s english locale.

rails g scaffold Preparado nombre:string

I get the wrong plural: Preparadoes, It must be: Preparados.

On the console I tried this:

```
irb(main):015:0> I18n.locale = 'es'
=> "es"
irb(main):016:0> 'preparado'.pluralize()
=> "preparadoes"
irb(main):017:0> 'preparado'.pluralize(:es)
=> "preparados"
irb(main):018:0>
```

My gemFile contains:

```
gem 'inflections'
```

In summary, I need to create an scaffold with the correct pluralization.

Sorry by my english. I know it ´s not the best.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i18n does not affect pluralization here, rails uses inflections for it, and there is only one method I know to customize it:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect| 
   inflect.irregular 'preparado', 'preparados' 
end
```

to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

There is [Spanish locale](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7db0b073fec6bc3e6f213b58c76e7f43fcc2ab97) for `#pluralize`, but you need to set it explicitly every time you call it. And [generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/railties/lib/rails/generators/model_helpers.rb) calls it without parameters.